# Plugin Not defined error in PhoneGap 3.4 in android

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to write my own plugin for calling an another activity from html file using phonegap 3.4. But facing a lot of problem in customplugin.js file.

I have been working on this but could not rectify it. It worked in 1.6 version. But I want to work on phonegap 3.4.

Below are the codes which I am using.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- If your application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="customplugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function onBodyLoad()
    {       
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    /* When this function is called, Cordova has been initialized and is ready to roll */
    /* If you are supporting your own protocol, the var invokeString will contain any arguments to the app launch.
    see http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
    for more details -jm */
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        // do your thing!
        alert("Cordova is working")
    }

    function callNativePlugin( returnSuccess ) {
        a=10;
        CustomPlugin.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess );
    }

    function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
       alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
    }

    function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) {
       alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
    }



    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
        <h1>Hey, it's Cordova!</h1>

        <button onclick="callNativePlugin('success');">Click to invoke the Native Plugin with an SUCCESS!</button>
        <button onclick="callNativePlugin('error');">Click to invoke the Native Plugin with an ERROR!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the customplugin.js file.

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/cordovaplugin", 
  function(require, exports, module) {

var CustomPlugin = {

    callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) {
        return cordova.exec(success, fail, "CustomPlugin", "nativeAction", [resultType,"hello"]);
    }
};

});
```

Here is the CordovaPlugin.java file.

```
package com.phonegap.helloworld;


import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin
{



    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {


        //
        startPhotoEditActivity();
        PluginResult mPlugin = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        mPlugin.setKeepCallback(true);
        return mPlugin;
    }



    public void startPhotoEditActivity() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.cordova.getActivity(),SecActivity.class);       
        ((Activity) this.cordova).startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is how I added the plugin in config.xml file

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.helloworld.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

And finally here is the error I am getting.

```
06-01 20:20:37.579: D/CordovaLog(28742): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 33 :            Uncaught ReferenceError: CustomPlugin is not defined
06-01 20:20:37.579: I/chromium(28742): [INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: CustomPlugin is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (33)
```

I am unable to find a solution for this after a long search in internet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "customplugin" instead of "cordovaplugin" in the very first line of customplugin.js

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is: v3.4 has introduced some defects to prevent plugin to work properly.

Here is an similar example of unknown plugin error in v3.4:

```
03-25 18:21:03.810: D/PluginManager(7273): exec() call to unknown plugin: AdMob
```

The problem is finally resolved by downgrade cordova from v3.4 to v3.3.

As the defect is fixed in v3.5, so you'd better update to v3.5.